# Append to data list write to CSV

Tags: python, list, csv, append

I am trying to write a program that records the last three attempts (scores) of a test. The user can retake the test at any point so the program must find if the user exists and append the users latest score. If the user does not exist it must record the users name alongside the users first attempt. I have managed to get the program/function to record a users first score but I am struggling to append further attempts if a user exists. I also have no idea how I stop the list from growing  - it should only record the last three attempts - further attempts should rewrite over the existing. Please excuse my ignorance if this is wrong - I am learning.

I need the output to look like: (after 3 attempts the list needs to start overwriting itself

Fred,18,17,16

Paul,15,12,16

The code doesn't do exactly what I want it to do but the only error I get is when the user already exists:     scoresFile.write(line + "\n")
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

```
#add score
def main():
    #ask for name and score
    name = input("Please enter the name you wish to add")
    score = input("Please enter the high score")
    message=""

    #open the highscores line and read in all the lines to a list called ScoresList. Then close the file.
    scoresFile = open("highscores.txt","r")
    ScoresList = scoresFile.readlines()
    scoresFile.close()

    #for each line in the ScoresList list
    for i in range(0, len(ScoresList) ):

        #check to see if the name is in the line
        if name in ScoresList[i]:

            #append the score to the end of the list
            ScoresList[i] = (name + (str(score) + ","))

            #write the scores back to the file. Overwrite with the new list
            scoresFile = open("highscores.txt","w")
            for line in ScoresList:
                scoresFile.write(line + "\n")
                scoresFile.close()

            #no need to continue in the loop so break out.
            #break
            else:
                # message as user does not exist
                message = ""

#if message is still blank then it means that the name was not found. Open the
#file for appending and add the new name and score to the end.
    if message=="":
        message = "New score added."
        scoresFile = open("highscores.txt","a")
        scoresFile.write(name + str(score)+"\n")
        scoresFile.close()


    print(message)

main()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include sample input, the output you are getting, the output you would like to be getting, and any errors or tracebacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One self-explained solution to your problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# name,score_1,score_2,score_3
# append score to a user
# |_ if user not exists: add user and new score
# |_ an user can't have more than 3 scores


SCORE_FILENAME  = "highscores.txt"
MAX_SCORES = 3

def getName():
    return raw_input("Please enter the name you wish to add: ").strip()
def getScore():
    return raw_input("Please enter the high score: ").strip()
def log(*msg):
    print "\t[LOG] " + " ".join([word for word in msg])


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Get new name and Score:
    newName = getName()
    newScore = getScore()
    log("NewUser and NewScore = %s,%s" % (newName,newScore))

    # open file and get actual scores:
    log("Opening score file: %s" % SCORE_FILENAME)
    try: scoresFile = open(SCORE_FILENAME, "r+")
    except IOError: scoresFile = open(SCORE_FILENAME, "w+") # File not exists
    actualScoresTable = []
    for line in scoresFile:
        tmp = line.strip().replace("\n","").split(",")
        actualScoresTable.append({
            "name": tmp[0],
            "scores": tmp[1:],
        })
    scoresFile.close()
    log("Actual score table: %s" % actualScoresTable)

    # update scores or insert new record:
    new = True
    for index, record in enumerate( actualScoresTable ):
        if record["name"] == newName:
            # The user exists in scores table, check how many scores he has:
            if len(record["scores"]) >= MAX_SCORES: 
                # Max. Scores permitted. What to do here?
                log("Actual user '%s' already have %s scores '%s'. What we have to do now?" % (newName, MAX_SCORES, ",".join(record["scores"])))
            else:
                log("Add score '%s' to '%s' that now have [%s]" % (newScore,newName,",".join(record["scores"])))
                actualScoresTable[index]["scores"].append(newScore)
            new = False
            break
    if new:
        log("User '%s' not exists in actual Scores Table. So append it." % newName)
        actualScoresTable.append({
            "name": newName,
            "scores": [newScore],
        })

    # Save result to file and close it:
    scoresFile = open(SCORE_FILENAME, "w+") # Truncating file (write all again)
    for record in actualScoresTable:
        scoresFile.write( "%s,%s\n" % (record["name"], ",".join(record["scores"])) )
    log("Writing changes to file: %s" % actualScoresTable)
    scoresFile.close()
```

NOTES:

1. There are many different changes to improve this solution (operate in a opened file with `with`, direct write if it's an record update -not truncate file,...). I wanted to put this way to be more clear due your nickname: "learningpython" ;)
2. I don't know what you want to do if the user has already the three scores (start over again, delete from first added, delete from last added (...), so I did't code that..

EDIT to fit the new requirements:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# name,score_1,score_2,score_3
# append score to a user
# |_ if user not exists: add user and new score
# |_ an user can't have more than 3 scores


SCORE_FILENAME  = "highscores.txt"
MAX_SCORES = 3

def getName():
    return raw_input("Please enter the name you wish to add: ").strip()
def getScore():
    return raw_input("Please enter the high score: ").strip()
def log(*msg):
    print "\t[LOG] " + " ".join([word for word in msg])


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Get new name and Score:
    newName = getName()
    newScore = getScore()
    log("NewUser and NewScore = %s,%s" % (newName,newScore))

    # open file and get actual scores:
    log("Opening score file: %s" % SCORE_FILENAME)
    try: scoresFile = open(SCORE_FILENAME, "r+")
    except IOError: scoresFile = open(SCORE_FILENAME, "w+") # File not exists
    actualScoresTable = []
    for line in scoresFile:
        tmp = line.strip().replace("\n","").split(",")
        actualScoresTable.append({
                                 "name": tmp[0],
                                 "scores": tmp[1:],
                                 })
    scoresFile.close()
    log("Actual score table: %s" % actualScoresTable)

    # update scores or insert new record:
    new = True
    for index, record in enumerate( actualScoresTable ):
        if record["name"] == newName:
            # The user exists in scores table, append new score:
            log("User '%s' exists in actual Scores Table. So append score '%s' to him." % (newName,newScore))
            actualScoresTable[index]["scores"].append(newScore)
            # if now we have more than 3 scores, we delete the first one (the oldest one):
            if len(record["scores"]) > MAX_SCORES:
                log("User '%s' reached max. scores record history, so append score '%s' to him, and delete the oldest: '%s'" % (newName,newScore,actualScoresTable[index]["scores"][0]))
                actualScoresTable[index]["scores"].pop(0) # OR del actualScoresTable[index]["scores"][0]
            new = False
            break
    if new:
        log("User '%s' not exists in actual Scores Table. So append it." % newName)
        actualScoresTable.append({
                                 "name": newName,
                                 "scores": [newScore],
                                 })

    # Save result to file and close it:
    scoresFile = open(SCORE_FILENAME, "w+") # Truncating file (write all again)
    for record in actualScoresTable:
        scoresFile.write( "%s,%s\n" % (record["name"], ",".join(record["scores"])) )
    log("Writing changes to file: %s" % actualScoresTable)
    scoresFile.close()
```

Comment: Excellent. Ultimately when the user has threescores I would like the program to start again, deleting and replacing from the first score. Any additional.help would be appreciated.

Comment: To start the scores again with the user in the same position of the file, you just have to insert in this `if` (`if len(record["scores"]) >= MAX_SCORES`) the following: `actualScoresTable[index]["scores"] = [newScore]`

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain myself very well. I need the program to keep rewriting over the scores, (replace then one-by-one) so that at any one point the list will contain the last 3 or latest 3 scores. Once again any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So, for example from `Arthur,3,4,7` (if I insert a 9 for Arthur) to `Arthur,4,7,9`?

Comment: @learningpython I edited my answer with new code to fit this rule

Comment: Rather than using new= True, False etc and the if new: could I simplify it by using an else statement?  - nested if statements followed by an else statement. Also because the csv is being formatted during the writing of the file do I need the line tmp= line.strip().replace("n"'"").split(","). Finally what does enumerate do I have never come across it before. Still learning!

Comment: If you use else statement inside the loop to recognize where we have a new user inserted may be not correct because if you don't reached the end of the loop, the user you are looking for could be the next one in the loop. It's because I use the flag `new` to identify if it's a new user at the end of the loop execution.

Comment: `enumerate Python builtin function` https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate